# jQuery ajax only works locally but not on Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my front-end sends a jquery-ajax request to a back-end in order get values to calculate something. This works fine on my local webserver but if i do it online, i only get result 0 in my calculations, which means that i dont get the ajax response.

Here is my ajax-method:

```
function transmitToBackend(weights, subfeatures) {
    $.post("../Backend/StartFeasibilityAnalysis.php", {
        features: JSON.stringify(weights), 
        subfeatures: JSON.stringify(subfeatures)
    }, function(data){
        convertData(data);
    });
}
```

Could it be that the convertData(data) Method gets called before the data was transmitted from the back-end?

Best regards

Comment: Have you check the error console? Any error?

Comment: could be a problem with `../Backend/StartFeasibilityAnalysis.php` relative path check if you are getting `404` or any other error in your console

Comment: Take a look at the network traffic, check if the request and response are the ones you expect to be (Developer tools/Firebug -> Network)

Comment: In the chrome developer tools on the network-tab, it looks like the POST-request is OK but i don't see any response. I am talking about this site: http://thirdhorizon.de/access/Frontend/ui.php

Comment: Are you using windows as local ? if yes then check function name should not have lowercase and uppercase difference.

Comment: No i'm using a mac, i don't think thats the problem. As i mentioned, when looking at the network-tab in the chrome developer tools after i pushed the "serialize" button on  thirdhorizon.de/access/Frontend/ui.php , then there is the right http-request but i dont see any response

Answer (score 1):

> Could it be that the convertData(data) Method gets called before the data was transmitted from the back-end?

Nope, the callback is only executed after a successful response is received.

As for not working on the server, check if you can ping the url or use dev tools to check the http response code.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta check your Console first. If it can't find the resource (404 HTTP Response Code), there is something wrong with your URL.
You can definitely use relative Paths with an ajax call.
I only wonder why do you start with 2 dots?
If you don't get a 404 try to use your method like this:

```
function transmitToBackend(weights, subfeatures) {
    $.post("/Backend/StartFeasibilityAnalysis.php", {
        features: JSON.stringify(weights), 
        subfeatures: JSON.stringify(subfeatures)
    }, function(data){
        convertData(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: The dots are used because the front-end and back-end files are in different folders. There is no 404-error i guess, you can check it by klicking on the serialize button -> http://thirdhorizon.de/access/Frontend/ui.php

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
function transmitToBackend(weights, subfeatures) {
$.post("{yourdomain/ip}/Backend/StartFeasibilityAnalysis.php", {
    features: JSON.stringify(weights), 
    subfeatures: JSON.stringify(subfeatures)
}, function(data){
    convertData(data);
});
}
```